# How to convert audio to HE-AAC?

Tags: audio, conversion, aac, ac3

How to convert an .eac3, .ac3, .aac or any similar audio file to HE-AAC? (6 channel-192/224/244kbps)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use FFmpeg and use its `libfdk_aac` codec, which has AAC-HE support. Check out this page: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC. According to this, you could try:

`ffmpeg -i input.m4a -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he_v2 -b:a 32k output.m4a`

Option `-profile:a aac_he_v2`ensures you are using version 2 of the codec which supports 2+ channels.

Be aware that HE-AAC might not be compatible with too many hardware decoders, so check that first unless you do playback on a computer only.

Comment: How to get or add ''libfdk_aac'' this?

Comment: Maybe you find the requested info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932800/how-to-install-libfdk-aac-for-ffmpeg